# Looking for the simplest way to scale x-axis labels of a data frame plot

Tags: python, pandas

I'm plotting two columns from a data frame as follows:

```
ax=df[['Fp1','Fp2']].plot(title='Channels Fp1 and Fp2')
ax.set_xlabel("time (sec)")
ax.set_ylabel("mV")
```

What is the simplest way to scale the values shown on the axis axis? Currently, they are the index values. I simply want to divide each label value by 1/200 so that the values read 0, .5, 1, 1.5, 2, which will be in seconds for my example.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can set the ticks manually:

```
ax.set_xticks(df.index, [i / 200 for i in df.index])
```

Comment: Working in a colab notebook, this produces about 400 lines each stating something like <matplotlib.axis.XTick at 0x7f06053cc410>, which are eventually followed by my original graph. Isn't your approach going to simply use all 400 index values as labels, just scaled? I want to take the four existing default values, 0, 100, 200, 300, and 400 and scale them.

Comment: To avoid printing the lines, try ending the statement with a semicolon. 

ax.set_xticks(df.index, [i / 200 for i in df.index]);

Comment: That didn't seem to do it for me. Here's what ended up working:
    ```ticks=[0,100,200,300,400]```

    ```ax.set_xticks(ticks)```

    ```labels=[str(tick/200) for tick in ticks]```

    ```ax.set_xticklabels(labels)```

Comment: Good! You can also define the labels before and pass everything within the ax.set_xticks() to make it simpler.